# hola buen dia tengo problemas con este error Error de SQL (2008): el cliente MySQL se quedó sin memoria

Tags: mariadb

me sale este error se que pasa algo pero no lo sé. ayuda
Error de SQL (2008): el cliente MySQL se quedó sin memoria

### ya intente con el --quick y no ha funcionado

Comment: mysql, sql-server o mariadb? Son cosas diferentes. Otra pregunta: podríás por favor editar la pregunta y añadir el mensaje de error completo para ver dónde te pelea por sintaxis? Y un favor: sin mayúsculas sostenidas; no hace falta que grites. Gracias!

Comment: PD. Esas líneas que dicen `Load data from CSV file to ... you must replace blabla` y `clean table blabla`.... tiene toda la pinta de que estás copiando y pegando sin mucho análisis y estás intentando ejecutar **comentarios**. Seguro que toca ejecutar todas esas líneas?

Comment: Realmente este sricp me lo han pasado me vota el siguiente error y la verdad estoy perdida /* Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Clean  table expedientes_tmp for new data load.
TRUNCATE TABLE `snr`.`expedi...' at line 1 */

Comment: se supone que es para copiar los datos que envio desde un archivo a heidisql

Comment: Pues eso. El script tiene unos comentarios sin comentar (`-- comentario sql`) que son los que generan los errores.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba comentando las líneas que parecen comentarios. ¿Entiendes que no hay una instrucción `Clean table` o que la frase `Load data from CSV` no existe en SQL?

```
-- Clean  table expedientes_tmp for new data load.
TRUNCATE TABLE `snr`.`expedientes_tmp`;

-- Load data from CSV file to expedientes_tmp table. You must replace 'C:\Users\amari\Downloads\sql\CucutaExpedientes.csv' wildcard with your csv file location.
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\jgarzon\\Downloads\\Montelibano\\4.SanMartin_Registros_Expedientes.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `snr`.`expedientes_tmp` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`ID_EXPEDIENTE`, `CODIGO_CIRCULO_REGISTRAL`, `NOMBRE_CIRCULO_REGISTRAL`, `FOLIO_MATRICULA_INMOBILIARIA`, `NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO`, `NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO`, `NOMBRE_VEREDA`, `FECHA_INICIAL`, `FECHA_FINAL`, `UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CAJA`, `UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CARPETA`, `UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_TOMO`, `TOTAL_FOLIOS`, `RUTA_TIFF`, `HASH_TIFF`, `RUTA_PDF`, `HASH_PDF`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `PROVEEDOR`);
SELECT * FROM expedientes_tmp;

-- Update value field for id_oficina_registro to required value
UPDATE expedientes_tmp SET ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO = 260 WHERE ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO IS NULL OR ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO = 260;

-- Insert values from view on temporary table to final table expedientes
INSERT INTO expedientes (ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO, CODIGO_CIRCULO_REGISTRAL, NOMBRE_CIRCULO_REGISTRAL, FOLIO_MATRICULA_INMOBILIARIA, NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO, NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO, NOMBRE_VEREDA, FECHA_INICIAL, FECHA_FINAL, UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CAJA, UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CARPETA, UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_TOMO, TOTAL_FOLIOS, RUTA_TIFF, HASH_TIFF, RUTA_PDF, HASH_PDF, OBSERVACIONES, PROVEEDOR) SELECT * FROM expedientes_view;
SELECT * FROM expedientes WHERE ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO 260;

-- Clean table digitalizaciones_tmp for new data load.
TRUNCATE TABLE `snr`.`digitalizaciones_tmp`;

-- Load data from CSV file to digitalizacion_tmp table. You must replace 'C:\Users\amari\Downloads\sql\1cucutaAsientos.csv' wildcard with your csv file location.
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\jgarzon\\Downloads\\Montelibano\\2.SanMartin_Registros_AsientosRegistrales_2.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `snr`.`digitalizaciones_tmp` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`ID_DIGITALIZACION`, `UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CAJA`, `UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CARPETA`, `FOLIO_MATRICULA_INMOBILIARIA`, `FOLIO_INICIAL`, `FOLIO_FINAL`, `NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO`, `NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO`, `NOMBRE_VEREDA`, `TIPO_PREDIO`, `NUMERO_ANOTACION`, `TIPO_DOCUMENTO`, `NUMERO_DOCUMENTO`, `FECHA_DOCUMENTO`, `OFICINA_ORIGEN`, `NUMERO_RADICACION`, `FECHA_RADICACION`, `CODIGO_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA`, `ESPECIFICACION_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA`, `ESTADO_FOLIO`, `DIRECCION_ACTUAL`, `FALTA_FORMULARIO`, `FALTA_ANEXO`, `FALTA_TRAMITE`, `CONTIENE_PERIODICO`, `CONTIENE_MAPA`, `CONTIENE_CD`, `RUTA_TIFF`, `HASH_TIFF`, `RUTA_PDF`, `HASH_PDF`, `OBSERVACIONES`, `PROVEEDOR`);

-- Update value field for id_oficina_registro to required value into digitalizaciones_tmp
UPDATE digitalizaciones_tmp SET ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO = 260 WHERE ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO IS NULL OR ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO = 260;

-- Insert values from view of temporary table to final table digitalizaciones
INSERT INTO digitalizaciones (ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO,ID_EXPEDIENTE,UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CAJA,UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CARPETA,FOLIO_MATRICULA_INMOBILIARIA,FOLIO_INICIAL,FOLIO_FINAL,NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO,NOMBRE_VEREDA,TIPO_PREDIO,NUMERO_ANOTACION,TIPO_DOCUMENTO,NUMERO_DOCUMENTO,FECHA_DOCUMENTO,OFICINA_ORIGEN,NUMERO_RADICACION,FECHA_RADICACION,CODIGO_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA,ESPECIFICACION_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA,ESTADO_FOLIO,DIRECCION_ACTUAL,FALTA_FORMULARIO,FALTA_ANEXO,FALTA_TRAMITE,CONTIENE_PERIODICO,CONTIENE_MAPA,CONTIENE_CD,HASH_TIFF,RUTA_TIFF,HASH_PDF,RUTA_PDF,OBSERVACIONES,PROVEEDOR) SELECT ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO, ID_EXPEDIENTE,UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CAJA,UBICACION_TOPOGRAFICA_CARPETA,FOLIO_MATRICULA_INMOBILIARIA,FOLIO_INICIAL,FOLIO_FINAL,NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO,NOMBRE_VEREDA,TIPO_PREDIO,NUMERO_ANOTACION,TIPO_DOCUMENTO,NUMERO_DOCUMENTO,FECHA_DOCUMENTO,OFICINA_ORIGEN,NUMERO_RADICACION,FECHA_RADICACION,CODIGO_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA,ESPECIFICACION_NATURALEZA_JURIDICA,ESTADO_FOLIO,DIRECCION_ACTUAL,FALTA_FORMULARIO,FALTA_ANEXO,FALTA_TRAMITE,CONTIENE_PERIODICO,CONTIENE_MAPA,CONTIENE_CD,HASH_TIFF,RUTA_TIFF,HASH_PDF,RUTA_PDF,OBSERVACIONES,PROVEEDOR) SELECT * FROM digitalizaciones_view;
SELECT * FROM digitalizaciones WHERE ID_OFICINA_REGISTRO 260;
```

Comment: hola gracias me ha funcionado solo que cuado ya inserto los archivo me sale ahora este error  Error de SQL (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF3n arc...' for column `snr`.`expedientes_tmp`.`OBSERVACIONES` at row 1uery

Comment: estuve investigando y es un error de caracteres pero ya intente por consola y no se soluciona agradeceria tu ayuda

Comment: @ANA a menos que edites la pregunta y pongas una muestra del csv `4.SanMartin_Registros_Expedientes.csv`, no sabría que indicarte. El error está efectivamente en que el encoding del archivo es diferente al que indicas en la instrucción `utf8mb4`

Comment: ya he solucionado varios errores ahora me encuentro con este dilema

Comment: Error de SQL (2008): MySQL client run out of memory

Comment: ya intente con el --quick  y no ha funcionado

Comment: @ANA EDITA. LA. PREGUNTA. Y **añade** lo que necesitas resolver. Pon el comando que ejecutas y el error. Sin eso, nadie te va a responder. ¿De acuerdo?